# Do Facebook Messenger Extensions work in the desktop browser?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have not been able to determine this from Facebook Messenger documentation.

Do messenger extensions, as described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/extensions), work on desktop browsers? Or only on the mobile apps?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the MessengerExtension v2.1 and it can work on both desktop (Facebook Messenger Web App) and mobile (Facebook Messenger Android/ iOS app).

This is something the documentation never mentions at all, at least not at this page [/webview/extensions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/extensions).

I'm totally aware that adding those said headers are not going to work since those headers are completely blocked in the Facebook Messenger web app thus they are ignored no matter what.

I've found a way to make it work instead of following the documentation.

```js
window.extAsyncInit = function() {
  /**
   * NOTE: getContext works on both dekstop and mobile.
   */
  const APP_ID = '<YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID>';
  MessengerExtensions.getContext(APP_ID, (uids) => {
    /** Do more stuff here */
  }, (error, errorMessage) => {
    console.error('Error occurred -', errorMessage);
    console.error(error);
  });
};
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Facebook Messenger Extension now support both mobile and desktop. Facebook introduced this desktop support on their latest update on messenger platform V2.1. [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/changelog) is the complete list of new updates in V2.1 on facebook messenger platform.

Comment: "Messenger Extensions are now supported on both mobile and desktop. However, you may have to consider the following to make it work properly:" it saying it supports Desktop

Comment: Well that was recent update from facebook after july 27th update on messenger platform v2.1. I am happy that they made the feature available in desktop.